I can't delete cookies on production
I'm encountering an issue in production where cookies are not being deleted on signing out, causing users to be redirected to the main page instead of the login page. This behavior works as expected in development mode, but I'm unsure how to address this problem in production. Please, help.
signout page:
"use client";

import { useEffect } from "react";

import signOut from "../(main)/actions/auth/sign-out";

export default function SignoutPage() {
  useEffect(() => {
    signOut();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Signing out</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

signout action:

"use server";

import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

export default async function signOut() {
  const cookieStore = cookies();

  cookieStore.delete("refreshToken");
  cookieStore.delete("accessToken");
  cookieStore.delete("session");

  redirect("/login");
}


If you didn't use JWTs, it's always better to delete the session server-side.

@Evert I made a server call to delete the refresh token, but I removed that step for simplicity. However, I still need to clear the cookie; otherwise, the middleware will keep redirecting the user to the main page.

I accidentally discovered that you can enter an object as argument. Adding extra fields to the delete function, which isn't mentioned in the docs. This resolved the issue, although I'm not sure which specific field did the trick.
cookieStore.delete({
name: "session",
httpOnly: true,
secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development",
sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "lax" : "none",
maxAge: 0,
path: "/",
...(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" && {
  domain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DOMAIN,
  }),
});


I had the similar issue and solved it exactly how you did.
Here is my code for reference,
create session function:
export async function createSession(userId: string) {
    console.log('in create session');
    const expiresAt = new Date(Date.now() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    const session = await encrypt({ userId, expiresAt });
    const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
    (await cookies()).set('session', session, {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: isProduction,
        expires: expiresAt,
        sameSite: isProduction ? 'none' : 'lax',
        domain: isProduction ? '.xyz.dev' : undefined, // Only set domain in production
        path: '/'
    });
}

delete session function
export async function deleteSession() {
    const cookieStore = await cookies();
    const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
    console.log('Deleting session cookie. Environment:', process.env.NODE_ENV);
    cookieStore.delete({
        name: 'session',
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: isProduction,
        sameSite: isProduction ? 'none' : 'lax',
        domain: isProduction ? '.xyz.dev' : undefined,
        path: '/'
    });
    console.log('Session cookie deleted');
}

cookieStore.delete("session") was not working on its own, I had to add other fields exactly the same as in cookies().set to make it work.
And you are right, there is no mention of this in documentation.
